# php download link to rar

Tags: php, file, download, rar

I'm creating a website on my localhost that should let people download some .rar files.

In my index I've created some  tags like this:

```
$filename = "Test001.rar";
<a href="download.php?file='.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</a>';
```

This is just an example of one single file, but in my php file 'download.php' I've got the problem when I want to download the .rar file

This is download.php

```
<?php
echo "Welcome to Knowledge!";

if (isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file'])
{
    $file = $_GET["file"];
    $path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\TestSite'."\\".$file;
}

$err = $path.'Sorry, the file you are requesting doesnt exist.';

if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path))
{
    //get the file size and send the http headers
    $size = filesize($path);


    header('Content-Type: application/x-rar-compressed, application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    readfile($filename);
}
?>
```

It opens the stream in the right way, but I get that the file size is about 200 bytes and not the full length that is about 200MB.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what happens if you want to download the file? do you still get 200byte incomplete file?

Comment: No, it download a rar file of 200 bytes of dimensions, or something like that

Comment: Open the file in a text editor and see if it is actually text with error messages

Comment: It says "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 175652864 bytes)", so how can i allocate more than 13... bytes?

Comment: Whatever you do, do **not** set `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` as a quick fix, before some people suggest it.

Comment: This works, much thanks, i think that this set the limit of memory uploadable as illimitate, right?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **echo** statement, there should not be any output before the headers.  Change **readfile($filename)** to **readfile($file)**

Comment: It could also be a permissions issue.  Check the logs.

Comment: What is in the file that is downloaded - is it an error message?

Comment: No, it download the rar but if i see the folder it has the dimensions of 200 bytes or something near that value of bytes